# Why is the SizingGrip of StatusStrip not showing?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, controls

I want to add a `StatusStrip` to a `UserControl` and resize this `UserControl` at runtime. Here is how I add the `StatusStrip`.

```
  StatusStrip sb = new StatusStrip();
  sb.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;
  sb.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
  sb.GripMargin = new Padding(2);      
  sb.SizingGrip = true;
  sb.GripStyle = ToolStripGripStyle.Visible;
  sb.LayoutStyle = ToolStripLayoutStyle.HorizontalStackWithOverflow;
  this.Controls.Add(sb);
```

The `StatusStrip` is displayed at the bottom of the `UserControl`. However there is no `SizingGrip` (little Triangle) in the right bottom corner of the `StatusStrip`. Why not?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. I tried creating an empty UserControl, using your code to add a StatusStrip to it inside of the constructor, and then added that UserControl to an empty form. [I see the size grip just fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvebt.png) (it's just ugly because it's designed for a background color of `SystemColors.Control`).

Comment: I use the UserControl inside a Panel as a "Widget" that can be moved around within the panel. I made it resizable handling MouseEvents. But it is totally buggy if the Height of the UserControl is resized so i tought i might use StatusStrip for it. But obviously not. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not showing up because a `UserControl` is not a sizable control at runtime. The `StatusStrip`, nay more specifically the sizing grip, was built to support the `Form` control.

Here is the code for `ShowSizingGrip`, a `private` property used during paint:

```
private bool ShowSizingGrip
{
    get
    {
        if (this.SizingGrip && base.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            if (base.DesignMode)
            {
                return true;
            }
            HandleRef rootHWnd = WindowsFormsUtils.GetRootHWnd(this);
            if (rootHWnd.Handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return !UnsafeNativeMethods.IsZoomed(rootHWnd);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

at this point I can see two point of interest. First, `HandleRef rootHWnd = WindowsFormsUtils.GetRootHWnd(this);`, I can't test this class because it's `internal`, but there's a really good chance it's not going to return a window. However, even if it did, if said window was currently maximized, `!UnsafeNativeMethods.IsZoomed(rootHWnd);`, the sizing grip wouldn't show either.

My educated guess -- your window is maximized. I make that assumption because it appears Cody Gray was able to make it show up on a `UserControl`.

Comment: Yes, it was designed for a form. But why isn't it working for a user control? What is stopping it? Do you think the painting code checks that the object is resizable at runtime?

Comment: @CodyGray, I've posted the code that's used to determine its visibility. If the control is even able to recover the window with `GetRootHwnd`, the sizing grip would still be hidden if said window were maximized.

Comment: Excellent. That makes this a much better answer. +1

Comment: @CodyGray, thanks a lot! Sometimes it takes a little prodding to get into the reflected code, but the answer is always there. :D

Comment: OMG you are right. The sizing grip was not visible because the form was maximized.